# I am getting error while migrating a site to new web application in sharepoint 2010 ?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting error while migrating a site to new web application in sharepoint 2010 ? 
Correlation id is "6c589-b44-bc64-4f10-9c7f-f6e03dc87662". Please help to resolved it error and also i want to know how to know specific error from these correlation id, Since I am new in sharepoint..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read logs using correlation id navigate to following path,

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Here you will find all logs file. 
Filter the files list using last date modified then open the most recent file updated and search the correlation in that text file. here you will find the relevant info regarding the error.

For more info:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242586/Easily-Determining-what-is-the-exact-Error-by-usin